# R, Integrate at each point of array

Tags: arrays, r, convolution, integrate

I'm stuck with computing the integral at each point of an array. The idea is first to create a function ("Integrand"). Then, create a second function ("MyConvolve") that computes the necessary integral.

Here's what I did up to now:

```
Integrand = function(s,x)
{ 1/4*(abs(x-s)<=1)*(abs(s)<=1) }

MyConvolve = function(func,data)
{ return( integrate(func, lower=-Inf, upper=Inf, data) ) }
```

Now, running the code with some array, I get an error message:

```
SomeMatrix = replicate(10, rnorm(10))
MyConvolve(Integrand, SomeMatrix)
```

Which ends up with the following error message:

```
Error in integrate(func, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf, data) :
evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
```

I already tried vectorizing the function, but still ended up with error messages.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "computing the integral at each point of an array"
(your array is 2-dimensional, but `integrate` computes integrals of univariate functions)?
For instance, how would you compute it at one point?

Comment: Hi Vincent! Suppose I have a 10x10 matrix. Now I want my code to compute the integral (in my case the convolution product) for each single matrix entry. Hence, input a 10x10 matrix and get out a 10x10 matrix of the convolution products. Currently, the code is fine if I input a single point of evaluation. But multiple points of evaluation don't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to compute,
but if you want to evaluate `MyConvolve(Integrand,s)`,
where `s` takes all the values in `SomeMatrix`, 
then `apply` is sufficient.

```
sapply( SomeMatrix, function(s) MyConvolve( Integrand, s )$value )
```

However, the dimensions of the matrix are lost.
You can recover them as follows:

```
result <- SomeMatrix
result[] <- sapply( SomeMatrix, function(s) MyConvolve( Integrand, s )$value )
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent, this seems to be what I've been looking for! I tried sapply in several ways, but could not get it right. In case I'll experience some (unexpected) issues, I'll let you know. Have a great day!